# Can I define JavaScript global variables to use across multitple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I want to define a global variable in JavaScript that I can use across multiple html pages. Please suggest.

Comment: [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible instead you can use cookies to store the variables and retrive them in another html pages.

Use this function to set your cookies

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
{
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

and use this function to retrive cookies

```
function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}
```